# How to enable https for my magento site

Tags: magento-1.8, ssl

I am using magento version 1.8.

I have installed ssl certificates from godaddy and given the base secure url as https://www.mydomain.com. I have also selected both the options

`Use secure urls in frontend` and `Use Secure urls in admin`.

But when I try with https I am getting page not found error. And am not able to access into my admin page. My site is working fine though.

Comment: I recommend to set the unsecure url to https too, there is nowadays no reason to run ANYTHING under http only (without encryption)

Comment: Sure there is. Varnish and Magento Enterprise FPC.

Answer (score 16):

You need to change.

In the same tab  check `Offloader header`  value is  `SSL_OFFLOADED`

If you want to use ssl for all pages, then need to change Base unsecure Url

[image: unsecure url is also set with https]

[image: bottom part of the configuration (mind SSL_OFFLOADED)]

Comment: Yes It has the value SSL_OFFLOADED by default

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you have not properly configured the ssl , follow the instructions here
 http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/5238/installing-an-ssl-certificate-in-apache

The other thing you can try is to log on to admin and perform a reindex and empty cache,now since you cant login back to admin, try this ,

1. go to phpmyadmin or whichever db tools you use ,
2. find the table "core_config_data" ,
3. fetch the row where "path" = "web/secure/base_url" ,
4. you will see the url in the "value", change that to http from https, and save.

Try logging back to admin. and perform reindex.

Comment: Yes I did based on the instructions given there. My admin url is now https://www.mydomain.com , and the result is webpage not found. So am not able to login to my admin.

Comment: Can you share your url ? The admin url is generally of form "http://www.mydomain.com/admin" , Also did you change the httpd to http in db ?

Comment: I changed the value in db, but result is still the same.

Comment: @NishanthLawrence If you get a 404 on your admin hostname, then you are probably trying to access it, without the `/admin` part of the URL. If that's not the case, then first specify if you get a Magento 404 page or one generated by your webserver. If it's a Magento 404, then you are probably not passing the correct MAGE_RUN_CODE in your index.php.

Comment: It is a browser returned error due to the incorrect installation of https certificate.