# magento nginx http to https

Tags: magento-1.9, nginx, https

In magento сonfigured https for frontend and backend
[image]

But styles and js use http

How can I fix it?
on the server installed nginx

Comment: magento frontend https only works for onepage checkout, customer, wishlist. if you still see http, it means you have hardcoded assets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you checked in admin

`system => configurations` At **web** tab under general

In Secure tab from right side see all

Base Skin URL should be `{{secure_base_url}}skin/`

Base JavaScript URL should be `{{secure_base_url}}js/`

Comment: this is my settings [link]http://i.imgur.com/n3qQiiS.png

Comment: in above text `Base URL` should be your https URL

Comment: I don't understand, please explain

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/30758/how-to-enable-https-for-my-magento-site see image in answer

Comment: Thanks!
but now in browser 
Incorrect redirection page