# Make full site pages open in HTTPS

Tags: magento-1.7

Currently only LOGIN AND Checkout pages are HTTPS, others are HTTP. How to convert all website pages to open in HTTPS?

Comment: Go to `System > Configuratin > Web > Secure` and change `Use Secure URLs in Frontend` to YES. Make sure you add your HTTPS url in `Base URL`. Hope this is available in 1.7 v.

Comment: @AdarshKhatri All the settings enabled but still Frontend is not fully HTTPS secure. only Checkout and Login pages. I want all pages including homepage and product pages, etc.

Comment: Check this http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/30758/how-to-enable-https-for-my-magento-site

Comment: Add https in Unsecure url as well. This will make whole site running on https.

Comment: @gulshanmaurya I heard about it, but isnt this is a bad workaround? I heard some mixed opinions adding HTTPS to UNSECURE URL.

Comment: Not bad, this is a right way of doing this. And i don't know better way than this in my career of magento1 to make whole site using https.

Comment: @gulshanmaurya I heard some end up writing is code .htaccess that pushed all pages via HTTPS. What do you think of such method?

Comment: I don't know such thing but that is not a right way of doing this. If there is some way with .htaccess that can redirect to https will have to redirect all internal urls as well. In such case request response will have too much redirects which may cause slow page loading. Also there will be possibility of mixed content(unsecure content) warning in the page. Also it is not necessary that all server have apache it may be nginx that doesn't supports .htaccess . My way what i suggested you will work perfect in all the cases and you can manage this from admin. Just change setting and refresh cache.