# Process for installing ssl certificates

Tags: ssl

I need help on how to install SSL certificates. I have a backend developer but he's new to magento. We hang on how to get the certificates installed so we can enable the ssl.

We only need help on the process on how to get the files needed and installing them.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question about server setup and 1. not related to Magento, 2. the answer depends on the hosting provider

Answer (score -1):

@Nassir

I hope you have purchased SSL certification for your website.
There are couple of posts which show how to install ssl certificate!

Please refer below link:

https://www.cloudways.com/blog/how-to-install-ssl-on-magento/

Comment: Only relevant if you use cloudways

Answer (score -2):

Follow below steps to configure your **Magento** store with SSL:

Go to **System** -> **Configuration**

Click on **Web** under the **General**

Select **Secure** tab

Now, under the **Secure** tab you will find two options as;

```
 Use Secure URLs in Frontend -> Yes
 Use Secure URLs in Admin -> Yes
```

Change both options to **Yes**.

Below reference links will help, if you stuck anywhere;

[How to enable https for my magento site](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/30758/how-to-enable-https-for-my-magento-site)
https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/magento/magento_ssl.htm
https://community.magento.com/t5/Installing-Magento-1-x/Valid-SSL-certificate/td-p/20688

Comment: That's not answering the question, "how to install SSL certificates" (but the question is not related to Magento anyways)